# Getting "Unhandled promise rejection" error in testCafe test script

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm, testcafe

Created a test in testcafe, using Javascript in Visual studio code.
Not sure why this error appears, as couple of test cases are running fine with same codes

**Unhandled promise rejection:
ActionStringArgumentError { code: 'E16', isTestCafeError: true, callsite: CallsiteRecord { filename:
'File Location', lineNum: 23, callsiteFrameIdx: 6, stackFrames: [
[Object],    [Object],    [Object],
[Object],    [Object],    [Object],
[Object],    CallSite {}, [Object],
[Object],    [Object],    CallSite {},
[Object],    [Object],    [Object],
CallSite {}, [Object],    [Object],
[Object],    CallSite {}, [Object],
[Object],    [Object],    CallSite {},
[Object],    [Object],    [Object],
CallSite {}, [Object],    [Object],
[Object],    [Object],    [Object],
[Object]
], isV8Frames: true }, argumentName: 'text', actualValue: 'undefined' }
Browser: Chrome 96.0.4664.45 / Windows 10**

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you didn't set the 'text' parameter for some action (most likely, for 'typeText'). It should be a string but you specified undefined. Try to inspect your test and find the problematic action. If you cannot find it, please share an example with which it would be possible to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it and will come back to you, Once again Thanks for your help.